# JAVA - about ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi i have a question about ArrayList in Java.

I have in a class called "Utente" an ArrayList ricFriends;
Now, the problem is that i have a method called

```
requestFriendship(Utente u)
```

where i want to add in the u.ricFriends the object Utente that call the method...

I tried in this way but it's at 99% wrong..

```
public void requestFriendship(Utente u){
    u.ricFriends.add(this);
}
```

for example i want to do this :

```
Utente Gary = new Utente();
Utente Mike = new Utente();

Gary.requestFriendship(Mike);
```

And if i check Mike.ricFriends i can see the object Gary;

Sorry for the english, thank you.

Comment: According your description, requestFriendship works correctly: the object for which you call this method is added to the list owned by the Utente parameter.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: That looks like it should work, what is wrong with it?

Comment: It should add Gary to Mike and seems working. Do you want to add Mike to Gary too?

Comment: Sorry, i solved, it works

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you should change this line:

```
 u.ricFriends.add(this);
```

for this:

```
  this.ricFriends.add(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are making a attribute public, that's not a good practice in OO programming, you should create get and set methods.

About you problem, you could do it something like this:

```
ArrayList<Utente> utenteList = u.getRicFriends();

utenteList.add(Mike);
```

Take care about "this" pointer, "this" mean that you are taking the object reference himself.

Comment: Returning mutable lists is also often seen as bad practice in OO programming. I would prefer an `addRicFriend(Mike)` method. This would make changes in `u` easier - the internal detail, whether ricFriends is an Array, an ArrayList or anything else is encapsulated.